# Set up JUnit test database

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, testing, junit

```
void insertAllRecords(){
    insertRecord("tom", 100);
    insertRecord("jake", 200);
    insertRecord("tim", 300);
    insertRecord("andy", 400);
    insertRecord("mike", 500);
}
```

I am writing `JUnit` test for something that has a test database.  It starts as an empty database.
I want to test different things, but I don't want to have duplicated `insertRecord` with same params.

Is there a simple way to specify which line(s) to execute?  For example, I only want to add tom and andy in one of the `@test` function.

I KNOW IN EACH TEST METHOD, THE DATABASE STARTS AS 0.
I want to be able to:

- in testA, set up db with tom and jake.
- in testB, set up db with andy
  and mike.
- in testC, set up db with all of them.

But I don't want to put individual insert statement in every test.  I want to be able to call insertAllRecords with some parameters.

Thanks

Comment: In integration tests, you should rollback database records after a test completes. That way, you don't need to worry about duplicates.

Comment: i can probably have several arrays for each column and have a loop to add the ones I want.  IS THERE A BETTER WAY?

Comment: Why don't you mock your data? Something like mockito...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JUnit does not support the behaviour that you want. You might want to take a look at [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) which allows test specific setup with `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` annotations. And it also allow more flexible test data using parameterized data with `@Parameter` or `@DataProvider` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

convert your Junit Class to an abstract class with the abstract method `abstract void insertAllRecords();`

Then extend this class in the cases, you need. For example

```
class TestWithTomClass extends AbstractTestClass{
    public void insertAllRecords(){
       insertRecord("tom", 100);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTestWithTom(){
       ....
    }
```